# No heat flow is to thermal equilbrium as .... is to mechanical equilbrium?

Tags: thermodynamics

When two systems are in thermal equilibrium, this means that there is no heat flow between them. What is the analogous definition for mechanical equilibrium?

(I know that in mechanical equilibrium the pressure of the two systems must be the same, like temperature in thermal equilibrium, and this is not the definition I am after)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since mechanical equilibrium implies $\vec{F}_{net}=0$, that means $\vec{\dot{p}}=0$, so "no net flow of momentum."